# Ray\curve mirror problem

Tags: algebraic-curves, reflection

I have an idea for a space station, but there is the following problem.

I have a patch of grass on a space station. If the sun (yellow rays) shines from below it, what is the best shape of mirror (gray curve) to hang above it and reflect back onto the grass?

[image: reflector]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The real world applications of parabolas are exactly this situation. Depending on how you want illumination over the grass, modification to the original parabola (moving the focus down) suffices, otherwise play with the parabola formula a bit

Comment: Parabolas focus parallel rays to a point.  I think OP wants the curve that takes parallel rays and gives uniform illumination over the grass.

Comment: Ross is correct. I suppose I could make the parabola slightly out of focus so that the rays crisscross. But I am curious if there is another solution.

Comment: @posfan12 I have edited my answer

Comment: Any idea of the proper formula given a known size for the grass area?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to much light on your grass, as to much may well cook it or set it ablaze.
In my view, in this case, a simple flat or slightly convexe mirror could very be the best solution.